# Protractor running data driven test in parallel

Tags: protractor

```
for (let i in info) {

        describe(info[i].TestName, () => {

        beforeAll(function () {
        browser.get('http://abcsite.com');
        });

        describe('Login', () => {
            Login.start();
        });

        describe('LibraryApp', () => {
            LibraryApp.app(info[i]);
        });

});
}
```

Conf.js has:

```
suites: {
    runSuite: ['RunSuite.js']
},
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    count: 2,
},
```

How can I run data row 1 against browser 1 and data row 2 against browser 2, data row 3 against browser 1 and so on in parallel?

Right now it runs data row 1 in browser 1 and 2 and then runs data row 2 in browser 1 and 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to separate your spec files (so data row 1 gets an individual spec file and data row 2 gets an individual spec file etc) then and add the `shardTestFiles:true` and `maxInstances: 3` capability which will run test files in parallel.

As far as I am aware running different tests in the same spec file in parallel is not possible unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Fox Can I run different tests in same spec file in parallel via docker?

Comment: @SUM I don't think so..the same rule would apply when you are running your tests inside a docker container or not. The link provided is generally how it works https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/PD/Protractor+Parallel+Execution